# Beamer change Section/Subsection pages

Tags: beamer

in Beamer
Is it possible to make the following changes in Section/Subsection pages
as illustrated in the attached jpgs

1- avoid displaying the word Section/Subsection
2- involve the section title in subsection pages
3- colour code Section/Subsection pages

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
 \usepackage{xcolor}

\title
[]{\Large \bf My Thesis}
\subtitle
{}
\author
[]{{{\textcolor{blue}{\footnotesize H. John}}}}

\date
{{\small 2016}}


\usepackage{verbatim}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}










\section
[Int]{Introduction}
\frame{\sectionpage}

\subsection
[Scope]{Scope}
\frame{\subsectionpage}

\subsection
[Lim]{Limits}
\frame{\subsectionpage}






\section
[Mats]{Materials}
\frame{\sectionpage}

\subsection
[Mat1]{Material1}
\frame{\subsectionpage}


\subsection
[Mat2]{Material2}
\frame{\subsectionpage}







\section
[Meths]{Methods}
\frame{\sectionpage}

\subsection
[Meth1]{Method1}
\frame{\subsectionpage}


\subsection
[Meth2]{Method2}
\frame{\subsectionpage}





\end{document}
```

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per default beamer seems to use the colour `part title` for the boxes in the section and subsection pages. The following code redefines these pages with two independent colours, which can than be altered during the document to distinguish the individual sections.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title[]{My Thesis}
\subtitle{}
\author[]{H. John}

\date{2016}

\listfiles

\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=blue}

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Large, series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\small}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
    \begingroup
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{section title}
        \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \endgroup
}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection page}
{
    \begingroup
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{section title}
        \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vspace*{10pt}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{subsection title}
        \usebeamerfont{subsection title}\insertsubsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \endgroup
}


\begin{document}


    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame} 

    \begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    \setbeamercolor{section title}{bg=cyan!50!black}
    \setbeamercolor{subsection title}{bg=cyan}

    \section[Int]{Introduction}
    \frame{\sectionpage}

    \subsection
    [Scope]{Scope}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}

    \subsection
    [Lim]{Limits}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}

    \setbeamercolor{section title}{bg=green!50!black}
    \setbeamercolor{subsection title}{bg=green}

    \section
    [Mats]{Materials}
    \frame{\sectionpage}

    \subsection
    [Mat1]{Material1}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}


    \subsection
    [Mat2]{Material2}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}

    \setbeamercolor{section title}{bg=yellow!50!black}
    \setbeamercolor{subsection title}{bg=yellow}    

    \section
    [Meths]{Methods}
    \frame{\sectionpage}

    \subsection
    [Meth1]{Method1}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}


    \subsection
    [Meth2]{Method2}
    \frame{\subsectionpage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Remarks:**

- you do not need the package `xcolor` in beamer, beamer itself loads it.
- instead of hacking the appearance like `\author[]{{{\textcolor{blue}{\footnotesize H. John}}}}`, beamer provides very comfortable mechanism to control font size etc. for its various components.

---

```
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=blue}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\footnotesize}
```

---

**EDIT:** Meanwhile this problem was fixed in the Beamer development version (https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/d05925d68cd467188096eb4f6b8f1993058c0641). It should be included in standard tex distributions starting with beamer v3.49.