# Beamer change section/subsection pages font

Tags: beamer

@samcarter
In my post [Beamer change Section/Subsection pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304876/beamer-change-section-subsection-pages)
I got a very good answer by samcarter
How can I modify the code
\setbeamercolor{section title}{bg=blue!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{subsection title}{bg=cyan}

to define also the font size, instead of defining it in each section
\section
[Introduction]{\Large \bf Introduction}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change Beamer's fonts with the `\setbeamerfont` macro. The available options are described in Section 18.3.3 of the [Beamer User's Guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

For your particular case:

```
\setbeamerfont{section title}{size=\Large,series=\bfseries}
```