# Beamer theme does not show section, I want to enable sections

Tags: beamer, sectioning

In my beamer presentation using Metropolis theme I get to see slides corresponding to `\section{}`.

Switching to theme `CambridgeUS`, sections disappear.

What is the simplest way to use `CambridgeUS` beamer theme AND see `\section{}` slides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\AtBeginSection[]{%
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \usebeamertemplate{section page}
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. My next question was going to be about removing 'Section 1' headerline from sections. The answer is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304876/beamer-change-section-subsection-pages)